# Sed and grep regex syntaxes differ

Tags: regex, sed, find, grep

This is a part of my shell script, which I use to perform a recursive find and replace in the working directory. Backup and other utilities are in other functions, which are irrelevant to my problem.

```
#!/bin/bash

# backup function goes here

# @param $1 The find pattern.
# @param $2 The replace pattern. 
function findAndReplace {
    bufferFile=/tmp/tmp.$$
    filesToReplace=`find . -type f | grep -vi cvs | grep -v '#'`
    sedPattern="s/$1/$2/g"
    echo "Using pattern $sedPattern"
    for f in $filesToReplace; do
        echo "sedding file $f"
        sed "$sedPattern" "$f" > "$bufferFile"
        exitCode=$?
        if [ $exitCode -ne 0 ] ; then
            echo "sed $sedPattern exited with $exitCode"
            exit 1
        fi
        chown --reference=$f $bufferFile
        mv $bufferFile $f
    done
}

backup
findAndReplace "$1" "$2"
```

Here's a sample usage: `recursive-replace.sh "function _report" "function report"`.

It works, but there is one problem. It uses *sed* on ALL files in the working directory. I would like to *sed* only those files, which contain the find pattern.

Then, I modified the line:

```
filesToReplace=`find . -type f | grep -vi cvs | grep -v '#'`
```

to:

```
filesToReplace=`grep -rl "$1" . | grep -vi cvs | grep -v '#'`
```

And it works too, but not for all find patterns. E.g. for pattern `\$this->report\((.*)\)` I recieve error: `grep: Unmatched ( or \(`. This pattern is correct for *sed*, but not for *grep*.
Regex syntaxes for *grep* and *sed* differ. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

use `grep -E` ("extended" regexp option) — it usually solves the problem.

(also sometimes available as `egrep`)

Also, why not keep using find?

```
filesToReplace=`find . -name CVS -prune -o -type f -exec grep -l "$1" {} \; | grep -v '#'`
```

Also note the `-i` option of `sed`, which allows in-place changes in files and the removal of the bufferFile/chown/mv logic.

Comment: I don't get the error message, but the files containing `$this->report('foo')` are not found and therefore replaced. I also tried replacing the `(.*)` with `([^)]*)`, but no to avail.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that `$this…` problem. Maybe the dollar gets interpreted somewhere by bash?

Comment: I want to filter out the CVS files, hence `grep -vi cvs | grep -v '#'`. I want perform the find and replace on entire filesystem subtree, so `-prune` is not welcome ;) Sure I can keep using find, but does it change anything? I can see you exec grep through find, so it is basically the same thing.

Comment: @Dagguh: Why filter?  You are making it more complicated than it needs to be, keeping it in perspective this is a script it doesn't need to perform.

Comment: @Jack: I filter out CVS artifacts, because I need to see the list of files that were changed and I am interested only in those, which will be in the repository. If not the filtering, I would recieve garbage output, which then I would have to filter.

Comment: @cadrian: I double encoded the dollar and it worked found the files I needed. Thanks! `recursive-replace "\\\$this->report(\(.*\))" "\\\$this->report(\\1, 'bar')"`

Comment: I need to go now, I will edit your post, so it will contain the answer and then I will mark it. I'm gonna leave it here, for the time :D It is part of the successful output: `Using pattern s/\$this->report(\(.*\))/\$this->report(\1, 'bar')/g` which changed `$this->report('foo')` to `$this->report('foo', 'bar')`. It is funny how the literal parantheses are left unescaped, while the capturing group itself needs to be escaped.

Comment: that's one role of the `-E` flag. It reverses parens escaping. Edit to your taste :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why not compare source and buffer files before overwriting the source file:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    # backup function goes here

    # @param $1 The find pattern.
    # @param $2 The replace pattern. 
    function findAndReplace {
        bufferFile=/tmp/tmp.$$
        filesToReplace=`find . -type f | grep -vi cvs | grep -v '#'`
        sedPattern="s/$1/$2/g"
        echo "Using pattern $sedPattern"
        for f in $filesToReplace; do
            echo "sedding file $f"
            sed "$sedPattern" "$f" > "$bufferFile"
            exitCode=$?         
            if [ $exitCode -ne 0 ] ; then
                echo "sed $sedPattern exited with $exitCode"
                exit 1
            fi
            cmp -s $f $bufferFile
            if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
                chown --reference=$f $bufferFile
                mv $bufferFile $f
            fi
        done
    }

backup
findAndReplace "$1" "$2"
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not the issue.